# OK button on Bluetooth pairing PIN popup only activates after at least 16 characters are entered

Tags: samsung, bluetooth, android-10, bluetooth-pairing

This is on a Samsung Galaxy S20e which came with Android 9 and was upgraded to 10.
If I enter only 4 characters, the OK button remains inactive.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Usually* such problems are triaged by:

- First, clear the cache of Bluetooth app (you will need to enable showing of system apps in your app list from settings)
- If it doesn't help, do the same on the device being paired
- If still no luck, delete the data of Bluetooth app on both devices (all previously paired devices information would be deleted and hence as last option)