# Bluetooth -- is there a regional difference in implementation?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a new Sony Xperia 5 III

The bluetooth on it acts really funny. For example, when I get into the car, the car often fails to pair up with it, and I often have to go into the phone and manually connect the bluetooth. (No other phone, Android or iPhone, has this issue in my car.)

When I paired up with a megaboom speaker today, it took two tries, which never happens with the megaboom.

What do we think is going on?

Comment: This may help https://android.stackexchange.com/a/239489/131553

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks! That is not relevant, I am afraid. It has happened on fully clean systems (clean on both sides of the bluetooth story).

Comment: IDK if this would help but from developer options change the [Bluetooth AVCRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles)  to a lower /higher one

Comment: @beeshyams And where is that setting changed in an android phone?  I don't see it so far...

Comment: It would be under developer options (about phone - build number, tap on it 7 times or more)

Comment: @beeshyams FYI, I tried the "Bluetooth AVCRP" modification path. It makes no difference. The problem is the phone. Suggest avoiding that model, as Sony messed something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**: The Sony Xperia 5 III just has bluetooth problems with some systems.

There does not seem to be a fix. The fix is to use a different make and model of phone.